# How to ignore all row modifications on a FOR EACH STATEMENT trigger without cancelling the query on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

How to ignore all kind of table modifications `(INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)` in a `FOR EACH STATEMENT` `TRIGGER` without throwing/raising an `EXCEPTION` cancelling the whole transaction?

I know it can be achieved on `BEFORE` `FOR EACH ROW` triggers by returning `NULL` in the end of the `TRIGGER FUNCTION`, but that doesn't work with `FOR EACH STATEMENTs` function calls as they always returns `NULL` and the modifications are still applied.

(my motivation on this is performance improvement, as FOR EACH STATEMENT triggers are lighter than FOR EACH ROW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that.

Transition tables using the `REFERENCING` clause are out, because they can only be used in `AFTER` triggers.

You could use a view with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger that only modifies the underlying table in some cases, but statement-level `INSTEAD OF` triggers only fire if the event is handled by a row-level `INSTEAD OF` trigger, which would defy your intention.